# NotImplementedException on NAppUpdate Mono C#

Tags: c#, mono, raspberry-pi, auto-update

I try to have a console application that update by itself from a server using [NAppUpdate](https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate). I tested a sample console application on Windows to be sure it works, which is validated now, it downloads files correctly. But while running the same program on my Rapsberry Pi, I get the following error:

```
[UpdateHandler] : Preparing Update Source
[UpdateHandler] : Checking for updates
[UpdateHandler] : Check updates Completed
[UpdateHandler] : Updating
[UpdateHandler] : 100%
[UpdateHandler] : 100%
[UpdateHandler] : ERROR | System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the type initializer for NAppUpdate.Framework.Utils.PermissionsCheck ---> System.NotImplementedException: The requested feature is not implemented.
at System.Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity.get_Groups () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at NAppUpdate.Framework.Utils.PermissionsCheck..cctor () [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at NAppUpdate.Framework.UpdateManager.ApplyUpdates (Boolean relaunchApplication, Boolean updaterDoLogging, Boolean updaterShowConsole) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at NAppUpdate.Framework.UpdateManager.ApplyUpdates (Boolean relaunchApplication) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
at RunControl.Update.UpdateHandler+<>c.<TryUpdate>b__5_1 (IAsyncResult asyncResult) [0x00000] in <filename unknown>:0
```

I'm running the console application on a Raspberry Pi 3, with Raspbian Jessie Lite installed. Mono version is `3.2.8` (I only installed `mono-runtime`)

Sample code is here:

```
public bool CheckUpdate()
{
    try
    {
        UpdateManager _UpdateManager = UpdateManager.Instance;
        _UpdateManager.UpdateSource = PrepareUpdateSource();
        _UpdateManager.Config.TempFolder = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "TMP");
        _UpdateManager.ReinstateIfRestarted();
        if (UpdateManager.Instance.State == UpdateManager.UpdateProcessState.Checked ||
               UpdateManager.Instance.State == UpdateManager.UpdateProcessState.AfterRestart ||
               UpdateManager.Instance.State == UpdateManager.UpdateProcessState.AppliedSuccessfully)
            UpdateManager.Instance.CleanUp();
        UpdateCheck();
        return true;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : ERROR | " + e.ToString());
        return false;
    }
}
private IUpdateSource PrepareUpdateSource()
{
    Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : Preparing Update Source");
    return new NAppUpdate.Framework.Sources.SimpleWebSource(source);
}

protected void UpdateCheck()
{
    UpdateManager _UpdateManager = UpdateManager.Instance;

    Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : Checking for updates");
    _UpdateManager.BeginCheckForUpdates(asyncResult =>
    {

        if (asyncResult.IsCompleted)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : Check updates Completed");
            //still need to check for caught exceptions if any and rethrow
            ((UpdateProcessAsyncResult)asyncResult).EndInvoke();
            //no updates were found, or an error has occured...
            if(_UpdateManager.UpdatesAvailable == 0)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : No update available");
                return;
            }
        }
        TryUpdate();
    }, null);
}
private void TryUpdate()
{
    Console.Writelin("[UpdateHandler] : Updating");
    UpdateManager.Instance.ReportProgress += status =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : " + status.Percentage + "%");
    };
    UpdateManager.Instance.BeginPrepareUpdates(asyncResult =>
    {
        try
        {
            UpdateManager.Instance.ApplyUpdates(false);
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("[UpdateHandler] : ERROR ON UPDATE | " + e.ToString());
        }
        if (UpdateManager.Instance.State == UpdateManager.UpdateProcessState.RollbackRequired)
            UpdateManager.Instance.RollbackUpdates();
    }, null);
}
```

As the error shows, it finds update that are available, but fails in the `CheckUpdate()` function.

Comment: https://github.com/mono/mono/blob/0bcbe39b148bb498742fc68416f8293ccd350fb6/mcs/class/corlib/System.Security.Principal/WindowsIdentity.cs#L241

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks, but is there any solution to get around this issue?

Comment: Modify `NAppUpdate` to not use Window's features on non-Windows platforms:  https://github.com/synhershko/NAppUpdate/blob/19b8b0052a4bba9a3f1ac39e742957ba995e52d1/src/NAppUpdate.Framework/Utils/PermissionsCheck.cs